# which type of apk should i upload to google play store?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i want to publish my app without `flutter build appbundle` command because of some reasons.

I tried: `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`, I got 3 those 3 APKs:

`✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (7.0MB).`

`✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (7.3MB).`

`✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk (7.5MB).`

Which one from these 3 should i upload to play store in order to fit to all android versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that all users will be able to download your app on Play store you should upload 3 of them otherwise some people's device features might not be related to your apk so that they cannot download.

Answer (score 0):

Some user may not be able to install your app if you split the apk into different arm.

Try run this command if you dont want to build appbundle

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: this gives me fat apk. any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

To reduce app size you should upload `.abb` file. If you don't want to upload abb file then you should upload the fat apk which size will be almost 3 times bigger.
To generate fat apk you should run

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: because i dont want to upload fat i did split. any solutions?